# How to reset the value of Dataframe after each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read .csv files in a loop, in each iteration I want to read a file, concat values from one column and then in the next iteration same goes for another file. The issue is that I am unable to reset or drop the values in dataFrame hence it keeps the data from first file for each iteration.

Here is the code:

```
    for file in tweet_files:
        tweets = pandas.read_csv('../dataFiles/output_files/'+file , usecols=['date','tweet'])            
        for tweet in tweets['tweet']:
            concat(final_tweets,tweet)
```

Please guide either how to assign new object of dataframe to tweets object in each iteration.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `concat(final_tweets,tweet)`? Is `concat` a function that you defined, or are you trying to access `pandas.concat()` and in that case you need to assign it returned value to `final_tweets`?

Comment: Yes, that concats them, a function that I have defined personally

Comment: Then it would be helpful to post that function, so that we could see why it's not working.

Comment: The issue is not with concatenation, the issue Is that the for each iteration, tweets object contains data from the file read in first iteration, i want to reset the value of that tweets object after each iteration.

Comment: Do all files have same length(row count)?

Comment: NO, each file has different row count

Comment: @WaqarAli - If I understand you clearly, you want to take tweet column in all files and concat into single dataframe. Am I right?

Comment: I want to take tweet col from all files, one row against each file in final dataframe containing concatenated tweets

Comment: You have 2 nested loops: The first one goes over all of the files, and the second one is looping a column in a dataframe (which is generally a very bad idea in `pandas`, but without the seeing the `concat` function we can't help you with a better one). When you are inside the second loop, `tweets` is always the same. Only when you finish that loop, and start a new iteration of the first loop, then the file in `tweets` changes.

Comment: @Aryerez the inner loops works fine, but the outter loop doesn’t update the data in tweets object after reading a new file, this is the issue.

Comment: The code looks fine for reading different files. Please make sure that the list `tweet_files` indeed contains different files.

Comment: @Aryerez I have cross checked that the tweet_file contains  different file name, Yes it does contain different file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you clearly, this is what you needed,

```
df = {}
for file in os.listdir('../dataFiles/output_files/'):
    tweets = pandas.read_csv('../dataFiles/output_files/'+file , usecols=['date','tweet'])            
    df[file] = tweets['tweet'].values
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index').T
```

As you didn't provide sample data, I couldn't post sample output.

Comment: The issue is that each iteration doesn’t load data from new file into tweets object. It keeps data of first file read.

Comment: It's hard to understand why it behaves like this except you. print iterated file and check the result. try my suggested code, If it didn't work, point out the error.

Comment: The dataframe has to be updated, that is what I am unable to do, I am looking for a way to reinitialise the dataframe after each iteration

Comment: Yes, it has a better approach for concatenation but the issue that I am facing is still there.

Comment: Now tell me what is the issue in the code? where you are getting problem?

Comment: That the tweets object has data from first file each time the loop iterates, instead a data from a new file should be uploaded to the tweets object in each iteration

Comment: According my code, it does the same what you've mentioned. each time `tweets` dataframe loads new file. What you have mentioned is not possible unless you check `tweet_files`

Comment: I just cross check, each file contained same data due to which this happened

Comment: This is what I said to you from the beginning. take a look at updated code.

Comment: @WaqarAli - Have a nice day and Happy coding